# unable to view image using file path

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Issue: Unable to display image using FilePath

I have File Upload button which captured the file path & when I click on Upload button, it should be display the image which I have selected. But its not happening?

What I missed here?? do I need to convert the path to image url?? If Yes then please provide me the code behind it??

Thanks in advance..

Here is my code....

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim path As String
    path = Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName)
    Image1.ImageUrl = path
    Label1.Text = Image1.ImageUrl
End Sub
```

Comment: what is it showing there now? Is there any error? \

Comment: Just not showing the Image... that's it..

Comment: First you need to confirm that you've uploaded the image successfully. If you have, then there is a process of showing using drawing in asp.net. you can use .ashx(ext) page to show it. Search it. I've done it in c#.

Comment: Note that the `FileName` property of the FileUpload Control does *not* include the path. Plus it contains the filename as on the client's machine, it does not automatically get stored on the server.

Comment: @HansKesting I don't think he is SAVING the file after upload.

Comment: i have not yet write the code of saving the image at centralized location. From anywhere in my storage, end user can grab the image & using same path it should show on Image control.  Is this possible ??

Comment: Using the filepah,can I show the image in Image Control??

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to save the file?

`FileUpload1.SaveAs(string SomeFileNameOnServer)` should happen too, before you display from the server.

(not sure how the above line is written in VB.NET)

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim path As String
        path = Server.MapPath("~/.") + FileUpload1.FileName;
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(path)

        Image1.ImageUrl = path
        Label1.Text = Image1.ImageUrl
End Sub
```